# Why does Linux eat broadcast responses from 0.0.0.0?

Tags: linux, networking

I am writing a utility in Linux to manage a device on the LAN that doesn't yet have an IP address assigned. If the device responds to UDP broadcasts using a source IP of 1.0.0.0, it works fine. However, if the device responds using 0.0.0.0 (similarly to how DHCP works) then Linux sees the response in `tcpdump`:

```
13:01:38.388851 IP 192.168.1.36.57950 > 255.255.255.255.5005: UDP, length 5
13:01:38.389190 IP 0.0.0.0.5005 > 192.168.1.36.57950: UDP, length 0
```

but the response from 0.0.0.0 does not make it back to my utility (even if it's running as root, which shouldn't be necessary - if I can broadcast as a normal user, I ought to be able to get responses).

What causes the responses from 0.0.0.0 (in fact the entire subnet 0/8) to be lost? How much better is 1.0.0.0? (Do I need to make the value configurable? Or can we rely on 1.0.0.0 working?)

Comment: DHCP is an exception. Else 0.0.0.0 is invalid. Whatever the OS.

Comment: @A.B *DHCP is an exception. Else 0.0.0.0 is invalid.* Interesting. Can you provide a reference? My utility is working similarly to DHCP. Why is my utility not excepted? Or let's say I'm writing a user-level DHCP? Then I have to use 1.0.0.0? What does this restriction accomplish? *Whatever the OS.* Just now I wrote one that accepts 0.0.0.0 *without checking the application name*; gotcha.

Comment: Do you only have access to IPv4 for your utility? IPv6 always has link-local available as long as the link is up, which may be easier to work with.

Comment: Actually checking the reference, if the role of using 0.0.0.0 is to learn its address, then this is an acceptable use, but still has to be handled (by you, not the OS): https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1122#page-30 "(a)  { 0, 0 } This host on this network.  MUST NOT be sent, except as a source address as part of an initialization procedure by which the host learns its own IP address." . DHCP uses RAW sockets for this because the OS can't handle it either.

Comment: @A.B. Right, *sending* from 0.0.0.0 has to meet conditions, which might be an issue for the *sender*. But the link you sent doesn't put any restrictions on *receiving* from 0.0.0.0. So Linux seems to be assuming that a normal socket (even with root access) should not be allowed to perform any kind of address initialization procedure for other devices. What is the logic for this?

Comment: Somehow this _smells like_ a security restriction. It's easy to see how a UDP server could be tricked into bad behaviour when it tried to respond to packets from 0.0.0.0. I wonder if there's something explicitly blocking it in the kernel for that (or similar) reson.